# How to change the default table/model (User) for JWT authentication in Laravel and Dontrine?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am working on a project that was built on `Laravel 5.4.24` and integrated with `Symfony` component and `Doctrine`. I need to authenticate staffs on request from **`site_staffs`** table **`(SiteStaff model)`** and return the token. 
**`site_staffs`** table has these columns: `(id,`**`site_id`**`, code, number,..)`. Some columns have different names in the `SiteStaff entity` `(id,`**`site`**`, code,..)`.
There is another table for **`users`** and I have no issue to authenticate users and return the token. (In my case, I don't need to authenticate users and I just did that for testing).
The issue is when I try to change the default settings of JWT to authenticate staffs from **`site_staffs`** table as below, I get an error message (see down the page):

config/jwt.php:

```
//'user' => 'App\User',
'user' => 'App\Entities\SiteStaff',
```

config/auth.php:

```
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
     ],

    'api_token' => [
       'driver' => 'api_token',
       'provider' => 'users',
     ],

    //'api' => [
        //'driver' => 'jwt',
        //'provider' => 'users',
    //],        
   ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'doctrine',
             //'model' => App\Entities\User::class,
            'model' => App\Entities\SiteStaff::class,            
        ],
```

pi/SiteStaffController:

I am passing the credentials to JWT as follow:

```
$credentials = 
    [
        'site'     =>  $bpId,
        'code'  =>  $lanyard_code
    ];   

if(! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)){
      return response()->json(['error' => ['messages' => 
      ['Invalid credentials'] ]
   ], IlluminateResponse::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
 }else{
    dd($token);
 }
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to 

Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\User\EloquentUserAdapter::__construct() must be an 
instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, instance of 
App\Entities\SiteStaff given, called in /vagrant/vendor/tymon/jwt-
auth/src/Providers/JWTAuthServiceProvider.php on line 126
```

I tried many different ways and solutions but non of them worked for me. I appreciate if you could let me know what is wrong and what am I missing?
Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As per the requirement to change users table name for jwt auth in laravel need to follow two-step changes which I have tried.

I have changed successfully login/authentication table from users to a customer with following steps.

step-1: change below details for providers

**config/auth.php**

```
'providers' => [
    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'eloquent',
    //     'model' => App\User::class,
    // ],
     'users' => [
         'driver' => 'database',
         'table' => 'customer',
     ],
],
```

step-2: change in jwt file

**config/jwt.php**

```
// here to give a model path for authentication
'user' => 'App\Models\Customer',
```

Reference: [change users table name for jwt auth in laravel](http://guruquest.net/question/how-to-change-table-name-for-users-to-user-or-else-to-do-authentication-with-jwt/)

Comment: where is jwt.php file i cant find it in php lumen framework

Comment: @Saddan the jwt.php file is generated in config directory

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario I have two guards, web and api:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'managers',
        'hash' => false,
    ]
],
```

So, I follow these steps described in Tymon's Jwt Library docs:

"If the newly created 'api' guard is not set as a default guard or you have defined multiple guards to handle authentication, you should specify the guard when calling auth()."

```
$token = auth('api')->attempt($credentials);
```

In my custom api auth controller I had implemented login method as below and it works:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);
    
    $credentials = $this->credentials($request);
    
    $token = auth('api')->attempt($credentials);

    return $token
        ? ['token' => $token]
        : response()->json(['error' => \Lang::get('auth.failed')], 401);
}
```

Please, if this answer was useful for you, please give an upvote =).